# Loaded font doesn't show up when parent swf creates textField in loaded child swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts

Im working on a project that has a main swf file associated with the document class. It loads XML that provides the text content for the project, then it loads a swf that contains a font in its library, then it loads the first of several content module swfs. When the font swf has inited, I'm registering its library font with Font.registerFont(), and using it in a TextFormat object. After everything is done, I can add code to the document class to create a text field on the stage of the main swf and format it successfully with the TextFormat object, but when I try to do the same thing inside the loaded content module swf, the text doesn't show up there at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I should note that the TextFormat object I'm referring to is stored in an instance variable that belongs to the document class.

Comment: I've faced the same problem today. Anyone found solution?

Answer (score 0):

I love the difficulty of the question.

Never faced the problem, but first you may verify :

```
tf.embedFonts = true;
```

Or can't you simply embed the font with :

```
[Embed(source = "../bin/Fonts/book.ttf",  mimeType = "application/x-font", fontName = "bookEmbed", embedAsCFF = 'false')]
public var font01:Class;
```

then

```
embedFonts = true;
defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat("bookEmbed", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
text = questions.questItem[currentQ].questTitle;
```

(in this order, setting the text before the textformat doesn't worked for me)

Be sure you're using the embedded font's fontName for define your textFormat's font.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did set embedFonts to true. All of that worked when I created the textField in the main movie, but doesn't work when I create the textfields in the loaded swf.

Comment: The embedded font is loaded by the Main SWF or the loaded one ?

Comment: The font is in the library of a swf that is loaded by the main swf.

Comment: Can't you create a new font Class in the main swf, and copy the font in the other swf's content, then use it ?

Comment: If you could be more specific about how that would work, that would be great. Keep in mind that the main swf's document class is creating the textfields in the loaded swfs.

Comment: What I'd like more info about is the "copy the font in the other swf's content" part specifically.

Comment: Something like : 

public var Mainfont:Class = SwfLoadedFont;

Comment: That seems like overkill, since I've used Font.registerFont() to register the font, and Font.enumerateFonts() shows it as available?